# Google Tag Manager returning undefined on dataLayer variable

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to create a dataLayer variable so I can push the product name into the event label.

The dataLayer push when a user adds a product to cart is:

```
{
  event: "addToCart",
  gtm: {
    uniqueEventId: 107,
    start: 1666871102469,
    scrollThreshold: 75,
    scrollUnits: "percent",
    scrollDirection: "vertical",
    triggers: "30151582_46"
  },
  customer_id: "4cfa14bf-1749-47a3-9063-e19c0bc6f3a8",
  ecommerce: {
    currencyCode: "NZD",
    add: {
      products: [
        {
          name: "Panadol Rapid Soluble Tablets - Packet 20",
          id: "FAH262",
          price: 12.28,
          brand: "Panadol",
          category: "Web / Dental / Consumables / Anaesthetics / Pain" +
                    " Relief",
          variant: "",
          quantity: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried to create a dataLayer variable with the following

```
ecommerce.add.products[0].name
```

This is returning undefined in preview mode when I do test add to carts.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to change the DataLayer variable to

[image]

I can't really remember where I saw about this.

But when fetching data through here.

It is not regular get `products[0].name` but `products.0.name`